# Difference between Parsimonious model vs Optimal model

Tags: regression, model-selection, optimal, parsimony

As per my understanding, `parsimonious` regression model is the model that has less variables but with those variables I can describe the data best. Is it so?

Then what does `optimal` model imply?
I thought these two terms are same for model selection. But I read somewhere they are not!

Suppose, I have a simulated data where data is generated such that 1 variable explains most of the variance of response variable, and an other variable explains much less. And I have many other nuisance variables. Then in this case, does the parsimonious model contain only the first variable? Though the true model contains two variables?

Any insight is truly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the site. A huge part of statistics is the battle between parsimony and fit (optimal).  You can (almost) always get a better fit by adding more variables. So, why not add all of your variables?

There are several reasons and I'm not sure I'll cover them all.

One reason is overfitting. If you make a model on sample data and include too many variables, then the model will work badly on new data.

Another is that models are simplifications. As George Box put it

> All models are wrong, but some are useful.

Another is interpretability. A model with 30 variables is going to be harder to interpret than one with 3. (Not to mention interactions, collinearity, etc.)

There are some simple approaches to model building, but they aren't good. You have to think about your data, about your research questions, about your goals, and so on. It takes experience and practice.

As to your final question, the answer is "yes" but, of course, in real life, we don't usually analyze simulated data. We don't know what's going on.